# Is native method heavily used In JDK?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Here is a stack prompt for `SocketException`:

```
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
```

I noticed that `PalinSocketImple.socketConnect` is a native method. If I remember correctly, the `read()` method of `InputStream` is implemented in native, too. The execution of native method need lots of data type conversion, which may become a performance issue(I guess). All methods are finally implemented in a native way(call a native method). Is that correct?

Comment: The `read` method of `InputStream` is abstract, not native. (You might be thinking of FileInputStream?)

Comment: @immibis right. The only way to implement methods related to I/O is native. That is the point I want to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible to write a program without ever invoking native code from the main or any other user created thread. The problem is that it wouldn't be a very useful program. The JVM is just that, a virtual machine. It isolates the program from the underlying OS to provide platform independence. Native methods provide access to resources found outside of the virtual machine where your code is running.

All interactions with the OS have to happen in native code, since it is not possible for java code to directly interact with the OS. This includes IO, graphics, or even reading the current time. So yes, if your program does any type of interacting outside of the virtual machine, then it does so through native code.

Comment: Impossible is too strong.  It is possible - see JNode for example.  But it is not the way that any mainstream Java implementations work.

Comment: @StephenC I would say it still holds true for JNode. Except the underlying OS in this case is the actual machine, rather than another OS. You still need native code to access it's features, since you can't do it from within the VM. Unless they use some sort of AOT/JIT compilation with native code injection.

Comment: They do some clever stuff in the native code compiler.  There is a low-level "Unsafe" library, and the compiler turns unsafe "calls" into inlined instruction sequences; e.g. to access memory locations, do register I/O operations.

Comment: So the file I/O, network I/O are all finally implemented by native method

Comment: @Neo - if you are talking about JNode, no.  The "unsafe" native code implements much lower level primitives than that.  Everything to do with file I/O and network I/O above the level of "peeking" and "poking" device registers is implemented in Java.

Answer (score 1):

> All methods are finally implemented in a native way(call a native method). Is that correct?

No. All methods that call the operating system are ultimately implemented natively, and a few others that rely on external libraries such as the `java.util.zip classes.`

Answer (score 1):

> The execution of native method need lots of data type conversion, which may become a performance issue(I guess).

That is not the primary reason.  The primary reason is that most of the core native methods are wrappers for interactions with the operating system via syscalls and these typically involve things like hard pointers, and C-style structs.  It is not impossible to do such things with gnarly low-level APIs (similar to `Unsafe`) but it is a much better fit to make the syscalls in C or C++.

> All methods are finally implemented in a native way(call a native method). Is that correct?

Absolutely not.  Most Java methods are pure bytecodes, and are JIT compiled into native code ... with JNI / JNA / whatever "native" methods in sight.